# Difference between aggregator with sorted input and without sorted input

Tags: informatica, aggregator

My question is primarily theoretical. When we use an aggregator in a Informatica workflow and do not select the sorted input property, I assume the aggregator transformation sorts the data based on the group by ports and then does the aggregation.
To improve the performance of this operation, it is often suggested to turn the sorted input property on, and pass the output of a sorter transformation (with keys = group by ports) to the aggregator.
My question is: From the perspective of the map, the number of operations is similar in both cases: Sort the data, then Aggregate it. Why is it then that the sorter + Aggregator (Sorted input) runs much faster than a single Aggregator (no sorted input)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not correct** that aggregator transformation sorts the data before aggregation. It reads each row and stores the data for each group until it reads the entire source, because it cannot be sure where each group ends. Only after reading all the rows, it can perform the aggregation. Consequently, it uses more data cache.

When you use sorted input option, integration service assumes the data to be sorted by group, and performs aggregate calculations as soon as it reads all the rows for a group.

Performance improvement using sorted input is more significant when you have configured the session with multiple partitions.

Also, sorted input cannot be used, when you have nested aggregate function in the aggregator or the session uses incremental aggregation. Maybe, that is the reason aggregator does not automatically sort the data.

Comment: Are you saying that without sorted input an aggregator will end up reading the a file with N records N^2 times? Why doesn't the aggregator does an in-house sort to optimize the operation by default?

Comment: It reads each record only once from source, and stores it in cache which are  separated by groups. Because it is not sorted, it will cache all the records before doing any calculation. But, when using sorted input, it needs to cache only the records for current group. Not sure how you derived the number N^2.

Comment: Ok. What I understood was that it reads each group by port from the file then scans over the file again to see which group it belongs to.
Instead, as you suggest, the port would be compared with the cache and if it exists within the cache then the appropriate grouping will be done else will be stored as a new group. This seems more like a 2N (worst case, i.e. sorted unique values) scenario.
Do you mind sharing how do you know the answer to this question. I have been trying to figure out how the transformations work internally but have not been very successful.

Comment: It is what I had understood from the Informatica Transformation Guide.